# Python multiprocessing not running

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gis, image-segmentation

I tried to use multiprocessing on this for loop:

```
def segment_features(segment_pixels):
    features = []
    npixels, nbands = segment_pixels.shape
    for b in range(nbands):
        stats = scipy.stats.describe(segment_pixels[:, b])
        band_stats = list(stats.minmax) + list(stats)[2:]
        if npixels == 1:
            # in this case the variance = nan, change it 0.0
            band_stats[3] = 0.0
        features += band_stats
    return features

segment_ids = np.unique(segments)
objects = []
object_ids = []

for id in segment_ids:
    segment_pixels = img[segments == id]
    object_features = segment_features(segment_pixels)
    objects.append(object_features)
    object_ids.append(id)
```

By replacing the for loop section with this:

```
def segment_features_calc(segment_pixels):
    segment_pixels = img[segments == id]
    object_features = segment_features(segment_pixels)
    objects.append(object_features)
    object_ids.append(id)
    print("segment "+str(id)+" features calculated")
n=mp.cpu_count()
if__name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(processes = n)
    start = time.time()
    async_result = p.map_async(segment_features_calc,list(segment_ids))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("Complete")
    end = time.time()
    print('total time (s)= ' + str(end-start))
```

However, the multiprocessing does not get executed properly (multiprocessing stops after 0.17 seconds whereas the items to loop are close to 270,000+ segment IDs). Any insights on how to solve the issue?

Comment: I guess you want `map` instead of `map_async`.

Comment: Nothing happens because you don't do anything with `async_result`, which is just a lightweight object to refer to **future** results. Your program ends because you don't tell Python to wait for the results to complete. If you are just starting out with multiprocessing, `p.map()` is simpler to use: a call to it will do the necessary waiting for you.